# Bourbon Neat and semantic HTML5, what about BEM?

Tags: css, html, bourbon, neat, bem

I'm trying to write a very minimalist blog as a way to re-learn html and css. I'm trying to understand what I should use to select the elements of my page between plain tags, id or class.

For exemple this is what one of my page coud look like :

```
    <body>
     <header>
      <h1><a href="/">My fabulous blog</a></h1>
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page two</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </header>

     <section>
        <h1>Latest articles</h1>
        <article>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>I like turtles</p>
        </article>

        <article>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>I like potatoes too</p>
        </article>

      <a href="#">Browse the archive.</a>
     </section>

     <aside>
       <h2>Social</h2>
       <ul>
         <li>Twitter</li>
         <li>Facebook</li>
         <li>Github</li>
       </ul>
       </aside>

    <footer>© 1546-2032</footer>
    </body>
```

So something very simple, and as you can see I don't use any class nor id.

And the css would look like :

```
    body {
      @include outer-container;
    }

    header {
      @include span-columns(12);
    }

    section
    {
      @include span-columns(9);
    }
    aside
    {
     @include span-columns(3);
    }

    footer{
      @include span-columns(12);
    }

    header, aside, footer
    {
      @include omega;
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm right but, as it is a very unspecific set of css rules, it is quite a good practice. And if I have to style one of these tags in another context a `<header>`tag inside an `<article>`for exemple, using a class should overwrite the type selector without any problem.

```
    .article-header {
    background-color: #eee;
    @include span-columns(12);
    }
```

For example

But then, I'm not sure it's the right way and I heard about the BEM methodology and I though I could use both as the same time, to get a nice scalable base.

But how much BEMed should my css be ?

Should I use tag selector first, for my main layout and then BEM styles classes for styling ? Or just go fully into BEM and use classes everywhere ?

```
    <header class="main-header">
     <h1 class="main-header__title"><a href="/">My fabulous blog</a></h1>
     <nav class="main-header__nav">
      <ul class="main-header__links">
       <li class="main-header__item"><a href="#">Page one</a></li>
       <li class="main-header__item"><a href="#">Page two</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </header>
```

scss:

```
    main-header {
      &__title {
      ...
      }
      &__nav {
      ...
      }
      &__links {
      ...
      }
      &__items {
      ...
      }

    }
```

But also

```
    <body class="body">
    [...]
    <header class="header">
    [...]
    </header>
    <section class="last-articles">
        <h1 class="last-articles__title">Latest articles</h1>
        <article class="article">
          <h1 class="article__title">Title</h1>
          <p class="article__p">I like turtles</p>
          <p class="article__p">But I also liek potatoes.</p>
          <p class="article__p">But I don't like them both in the same dish.</p>
          <p class="article__p">Except in soup.</p>

        </article>
```

and (scss)

```
    .body{
    @include outer-container;
    }
    .header
    {
    @include span-columns(12);
    }
    .last-articles
    {
      @include span-columns(9);
      &__title {

      }
    }
    .article
    {
      &__title{

      }
      &__p{

      }
    }
```

or just :

But also

```
    <body>
    [...]
    <header>
    [...]
    </header>
    <section class="last-articles">
        <h1 class="last-articles__title">Latest articles</h1>
        <article class="article">
          <h1 class="article__title">Title</h1>
          <p class="article__p">I like turtles</p>
          <p class="article__p">But I also liek potatoes.</p>
          <p class="article__p">But I don't like them both in the same dish.</p>
          <p class="article__p">Except in soup.</p>

        </article>
```

and (scss)

```
    body{
    @include outer-container;
    }
    header
    {
    @include span-columns(12);
    }
    .last-articles
    {
      @include span-columns(9);
      &__title {

      }
    }
    .article
    {
      &__title{

      }
      &__p{

      }
    }
```

I know it looks like a particularly opinion based question and I will probably get down voted for that but I think it's more about understanding how Bourbon/Neat and BEM work and how readable, reusable and performant the code could be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Use class selectors only, it'll make your code much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using classes for most of your styling needs. Doing so creates a level playing field in regards to specificity and increases reusability and portability of your styles.

Bourbon and Neat are just libraries to help you write Sass a bit more effectively; they shouldn’t force you down a certain architectural path. BEM is a good way to organize classes and increase clarity for other developers. Semantic HTML is all about semantics of the *content*, but don’t let that hinder code clarity. I suggest properly marking up content to represent it in a machine-readable way (i.e. markup titles with heading elements, lists with list elements, headers in a `header`, etc.) and using classes to inject style onto that content. But the two do not necessarily need to inform the other.